# Change PHP PEAR for mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working along with some tutorial on how to import Excel data into mysql.
The problem I have is that they used PEAR: for database connection and I don't know how that works. So I would like to convert the code to commonly used mysql connection string. I'm sure I've never seen PEAR or DB::connect used before.

Here's the code below.

```
<?php
require_once( "db.php" );

$data = array();

$db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/names", array());
if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }

function add_person( $first, $middle, $last, $email )
{
 global $data, $db;

 $sth = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
 $db->execute( $sth, array( $first, $middle, $last, $email ) );

 $data []= array(
   'first' => $first,
   'middle' => $middle,
   'last' => $last,
   'email' => $email
 );
}

if ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )
{
 $dom = DOMDocument::load( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
 $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'Row' );
 $first_row = true;
 foreach ($rows as $row)
 {
   if ( !$first_row )
   {
     $first = "";
     $middle = "";
     $last = "";
     $email = "";

     $index = 1;
     $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName( 'Cell' );
     foreach( $cells as $cell )
     {
       $ind = $cell->getAttribute( 'Index' );
       if ( $ind != null ) $index = $ind;

       if ( $index == 1 ) $first = $cell->nodeValue;
       if ( $index == 2 ) $middle = $cell->nodeValue;
       if ( $index == 3 ) $last = $cell->nodeValue;
       if ( $index == 4 ) $email = $cell->nodeValue;

       $index += 1;
     }
     add_person( $first, $middle, $last, $email );
   }
   $first_row = false;
 }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
These records have been added to the database:
<table>
<tr>
<th>First</th>
<th>Middle</th>
<th>Last</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo( $row['first'] ); ?></td><
<td><?php echo( $row['middle'] ); ?></td><
<td><?php echo( $row['last'] ); ?></td><
<td><?php echo( $row['email'] ); ?></td><
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
Click <a href="list.php">here</a> for the entire table.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But you do know the 'commonly used' connection method? The only thing you need to do then is make the connection with your favorite method, and then change the `add_person` function to do an insert?

Comment: Voting to close for being *Gimme teh codez*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from you post that you also want the `mysql_*` functions, not the newer `MySQLi` class. (Personally, I prefer the latter as I like the OO-interface.)

Then change

```
$db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/names", array());
if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }
```

To

```
$db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die ( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('db_name', $db);
```

And change

```
$sth = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
$db->execute( $sth, array( $first, $middle, $last, $email ) );
```

to

```
$query = sprintf( 
        'INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s" )' ,
        mysql_real_escape_string($first),
        mysql_real_escape_string($middle),
        mysql_real_escape_string($last),
        mysql_real_escape_string($email)
    );

mysql_query($query, $db);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that helped alot - I didn't even have to change anything. I just copied and pasted your code.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR DB is a depreciated database abstraction layer.  It's pretty straightforward to use (in fact I think it is cleaner than the native mysql functions).

```
$db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/names", array());
if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }
```

would be

```
$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost,  $dbuser,  $dbpass, $dbname)) or die("The site database appears to be down.");
```

Next,

```
$sth = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
$db->execute( $sth, array( $first, $middle, $last, $email ) );
```

would be:

```
$res = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO names VALUES ($first, $middle, $last, $email)");
```

This is a very simplified (and potentially dangerous) example.  Notice that you lose the built-in safeguards PEAR DB offers (prepared statements).  You could modify the above statement using the native MySQL functions as follows:

```
$res = mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )")
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($res, 'ssss', $first, $middle, $last, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($res);
mysqli_stmt_close($res); // CLOSE $res
```

The benefit of using the second example is that mysql ensures that the four fields are strings (the four s's in the bind_param function).  Good way to make sure your end users aren't inserting the wrong data type for the field.

The rest of your example just reads in the values from XLS.

Comment: MDB2 can for the most part be slipped right into the place of DB, though some functions aren't directly equivalent/available.

Comment: Exactly. A good guide on migrating from DB to MDB2 is here: http://www.phpied.com/db-2-mdb2/